# Google visualization Error "this.Ca.RZ is not a function" when i try to use hideColumns

Tags: javascript, charts, annotations

Here is my HTML code:

```
<section class="account-chart-block box">
    <button type="button" id="hideSales"  >Hide line</button>
    <div id='chart_div' style='width: 100%; height: 500px;'></div>
</section>
```

Script code:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    google.load('visualization', '1.1', {'packages':['annotationchart']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
            function drawChart() {
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
                data.addColumn('number', 'Kepler-22b mission');
                data.addColumn('string', 'Kepler title');
                data.addColumn('string', 'Kepler text');
                data.addColumn('number', 'Gliese 163 mission');
                data.addColumn('string', 'Gliese title');
                data.addColumn('string', 'Gliese text');
                data.addColumn('number', 'Hey mission');
                data.addColumn('string', 'Hey title');
                data.addColumn('string', 'Hey text');
                data.addRows([
                    [new Date(2314, 2, 15), 12400, undefined, undefined,
                                          10645, undefined, undefined, 10645, undefined, undefined],
                    [new Date(2314, 2, 16), 24045, 'Lalibertines', 'First encounter',
                                          12374, undefined, undefined,10645, undefined, undefined],
                    [new Date(2314, 2, 17), 35022, 'Lalibertines', 'They are very tall',
                                          15766, 'Gallantors', 'First Encounter', 310645, undefined, undefined],
                    [new Date(2314, 2, 18), 12284, 'Lalibertines', 'Attack on our crew!',
                                          34334, 'Gallantors', 'Statement of shared principles', undefined, undefined, undefined],
                    [new Date(2314, 2, 19), 8476, 'Lalibertines', 'Heavy casualties',
                                          66467, 'Gallantors', 'Mysteries revealed', 320645, undefined, undefined],
                    [new Date(2314, 2, 20), 0, 'Lalibertines', 'All crew lost',
                                          79463, 'Gallantors', 'Omniscience achieved', 10645, "Hey XIT", "XIT description"]
                ]);

                var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

                var chart = new google.visualization.AnnotationChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

                var options = {
                    displayAnnotationsFilter: true
                };

                chart.draw(data, options);

                var hideSal = document.getElementById("hideSales");
                hideSal.onclick = function()
                {
                    view.hideColumns([1,2,3]);
                    chart.draw(view, options);
                }
            }
</script>
```

I want a button that show/hide the first line in the chart.

With current code view.hideColumns([1,2,3]) is supposed to hide everything related with:

```
data.addColumn('number', 'Kepler-22b mission');
data.addColumn('string', 'Kepler title');
data.addColumn('string', 'Kepler text');
```

When i hit the button i get the error "this.Ca.RZ is not a function" in the top of the chart.
Something is wrong here but i did not realized where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From google docs [Annotation Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotationchart):

**hideDataColumns(columnIndexes)** Hides the specified **data series** from the chart. Accepts one parameter which can be a number or an array of numbers, in which 0 refers to the first data series, and so on

It seems that **data series** talks about columns with numbers. You defined three of them. So, to hide 1st data series (with corresponding annotation) you have to use index 0. To hide 2nd one you have to use index 1.

This is changed part (note, I didn't use `view`, commented out):

```
//var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

var chart = new google.visualization.AnnotationChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

var options = {
    displayAnnotationsFilter: true
};
chart.draw(data, options);

var hideSal = document.getElementById("hideSales");
hideSal.onclick = function() {
    chart.hideDataColumns([0]);     // hide the 1st line
    //chart.hideDataColumns([1]);   // hide the 2nd line
    //chart.hideDataColumns([2]);   // hide the 3rd line
    //chart.hideDataColumns([1,2]); // hide the 2nd & 3rd line

    setTimeout(function() {
        chart.showDataColumns([0]);
    }, 3000);
}
```

To show data you have to call `showDataColumns()`.

And one note: color of lines change when you hide one of them.